# miss resource in android studio

Tags: android, android-resources

Please help

```
setContentView(**R**.layout.activity_audio);
btnPause = (Button) findViewById(**R**.id.btnpuase);
volumebar = (SeekBar) findViewById(**`R`**.id.seekBar);
textseek = (TextView) findViewById(**R**.id.textseek);
btnPlay = (Button) findViewById(**`R`**.id.btnpuase);
```

When I build a project in Android Studio the resource file is missing.

How can I fix the problem?

[image]

Comment: Please post your XML file code.

Comment: Post your activity_audio.xml

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to clean the project and rebuild it in Android Studio. If that doesn't work, then you should invalidate the caches & restart. Finally, if neither of those work, you could try syncing with gradle files. Usually the first two actions resolve missing resources error for me.